# FileMaker 14 Graphing a Total Summary

Tags: database, excel, filemaker

Here is the example data in Excel format:

[image: Data and Graphs]

I have a name field, a time spent field, and a separate area that adds up the data per the name, as well as one that adds ALL of the hours and subtracts it from the total number that would be expected. The total number that would be expected can be an arbitrarily added calculation (it will eventually be the number of unique names * the number of expected hours). The top graph displays the data of each person's hours worked. So far, in Filemaker Pro 14, I have come this far. I can display that graph and and summary of each persons' hours. That bottom pie chart, however, is giving me trouble. I can only get the data of one person at a time in there, usually the first person to show up. I just can't figure how to calculate and ENTIRE field in one graph while summarizing by name in another.

Here's what I currently have in FileMaker:

[image]

Basically, where I need to go from here is to just get that pie chart to have the "Total" and "Uncategorized" sections where Total is the sum of everything under "timeSum" and "Uncategorized is the sum of everything under "timeSum" - 160, then I'd be done the whole thing. I've tried adding global fields, additional summary fields, sorting by a field that has the same variable for each record, and nothing works. The pie chart only displays the data for one person, whether it's in the sub-summary part or the grand total part.

Does this make sense? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data to be charted is an aggregation of all records in the found set, the chart should be placed in a grand summary part.

A summary field defined as `Total of [ TimeSpent ]` would provide one of two required data points. The other data point is not quite clear; to take your example literally, the chart could be defined to show:

```
List ( sTotalTimespent ; sTotalTimespent - 160 )
```

as the values, using data from current record (delimited data).

---

### Added screenshots:

**Data**:

[image]

**Layout:**

[image]

**Pie chart setup:**

[image]

**Result** (records are sorted by Category):

[image]

Comment: I'm getting closer with your help (using List is great, thanks), but sTotalTimespent only returns the data on one person's hours. So if you look at the FileMaker image, it should display 207 and 207-160, but instead is showing Cathryne's total, 47 and 47-206. This is likely because I have to sort the data by name in order to get the bar graph on the left too, and I have a relationship to the Time Spent data in another table. I can give more images to show the relationships upon request.

Comment: "*sTotalTimespent only returns the data on one person's hours.*" Did you move the chart to a Grand Summary part?

Comment: Yes, I did. I was able to get the desired results if I only display the pie chart, but the two charts are using different sorting. The bar graph displays the total hours of each person, the pie chart displays the total hours of the whole team. I can do this in two views, but it would be better if I can get then both into one.

Comment: Either I don't understand what you want, or what you did. The two charts are *not* using different sorting. The pie chart does not use sorting at all.

Comment: Okay, so I would say the problem lies in that. The bar chart uses sorting and the pie graph doesn't. So the pie graph is catching the bar graph's sorting and only displaying the data on one person's hours. If this still doesn't make sense I can edit the question to go into more detail.

Comment: "*the pie graph is catching the bar graph's sorting*" No, that's not possible. I have added some screenshots to my answer - compare them with your own setup.

Comment: Thank you. After taking your advice and starting over, I got it to work, at least the graphing part. I appreciate your assistance.